# Unique encrypted values for same string

Tags: php, encryption, laravel, aes

While using Laravel, I recently noted that when it encrypts a value the encrypted string keeps changing.

For example

**ecrypt('abc')** returns **xyzABCDXZY**

But if I run the same function a little while later:

**ecrypt('abc')** returns **xyzABDJSAS**

Now this has me really really confused. If the encryption result is different for each time the function is called how on earth are they able to get back the original value (**abc** in this case) upon calling the decrypt function?

I suppose it has something to do with the encryption function but I can't for the life of me figure out what and how. Can someone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: BTW it is encrypt not ecrypt I guess

Comment: Uhhh... typo! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fact it may be able to decrypt it, for example, the encryption algorithm can embed a variable in the encrypted data besides the plain text which was encrypted ( like a seed value ) and so the algorithm would

1) encryption: generate a seed, use that seed to cipher the data, hide the seed inside the ciphered data ,produce the final ciphered data

2) decryption: read the encrypted data, get the hidden seed and apply this to get the plain text

in all cases, the plain text data would be the same.